# SSH Service Connection - Cannot parse privateKey: Unsupported key format

Tags: ssh, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to setup a release pipeline to copy files over to a linux server via ssh. However when I try to run the release I get the following error during the copy task:

```
Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: Cannot parse privateKey: Unsupported key format.
```

I've tried generating the key multiple times with `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and uploaded or copied the contents of the private key directly into the Private Key text area in the service connection. All to no avail.

It seems like I'm missing something simple as I can't find much mention of others having issue with this.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this issue description](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/11439) one should **[disable preview features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/navigation/preview-features?view=azure-devops) of service connections** in Azure DevOps. Then edit your SSH Service connection and instead of pasting key source it should possible to **upload a key file**. This way there is no `Cannot parse privateKey` error.

Please use `ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 2048` to generate your keys (the **PEM** format is required). Additionally, when I didn't specify bits with the -b option Azure told me the key file was too long.

Comment: Additional note: in my case it was crucial to run the pipeline Agent job on an Agent pool with my own VM's. Trying to run Agent job on the Hosted "Azure Pipelines" pool gave me "Timed out while waiting for handshake" ssh connection error.

Comment: Apparantly this is the same for Google Cloud