# Azure pipelines ansible task stuck on SSH connection

Tags: ssh, ansible, azure-pipelines

Having Ubuntu 22.04 azure virtual machine with installed ansible on it and Azure pipelines Ansible task in YAML, when it comes to execute Ansible runbook azure pipelines task stucks on SSH connection as per screenshot below

[image]

From the screenshot we can see that SSH connection works okay and prints desired output to the console.

YAML build definition is as follows

```
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    include:
      - '*'

stages:
 - stage: 'SSH_task'
    displayName: 'SSH Task'
    jobs:
      - job: 'Build'
        displayName: 'SSH Task'
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        
        steps:
          - task: SSH@0
            inputs:
              sshEndpoint: 'SSHConnection'
              runOptions: 'commands'
              commands: |
                cat ~/.ssh/authorized_keys


          - task: ms-vscs-rm.vss-services-ansible.ansible-task.Ansible@0
            displayName: 'Run playbook'
            inputs:
              ansibleInterface: remoteMachine
              connectionOverSsh: SSHConnection
              playbookRootRemoteMachine: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
              playbookPathLinkedArtifactOnRemoteMachine: ansible_hotel360.yml
              inventoriesRemoteMachine: hostList
              inventoryHostListRemoteMachine: $PublicIpOfVM
```

More context around VM configuration:

- Keys are generated using command: `ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 2048` as per answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59103266/9541789
- Error: All configured authentication methods failed is solved as per answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74362454

Any ideas why ansible task stacks on SSH connection?

PS based on debug output of the azure pipelines task, it stucks on copying of playbook to the VM

[image]

I have added full permissions to `/tmp` folder using `chmod -R 777 /tmp` but error still there